# httr::GET in R returns invalid content type for a gzip file

Tags: r, get, content-type, httr

I'm running an `httr::GET` request that should return a gzip file.
I'm getting the following  error from R:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings.
```

When I run the same request from the terminal using `curl` it works fine.
(but obviously I need to be able do it in R)

The response code is 200 and here are some of the relevant headers of the **response**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: application/a-gzip
...
Content-Encoding: agzip
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you were able to share the url.

Comment: @AllanCameron Unfortunately I can't for security reasons, if any other information is needed I'll be happy to share